# Add temporary routes to netplan

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, and I need to add some routes. Which command shall I use?
`ifup` was deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject temporary netplan configuration by writing config files under /run/netplan and running `netplan apply`.  However, if these are temporary routes, there's no reason you can't continue to use the commands you're familiar with to configure these directly in the kernel ('ip route add', 'route add').